# One query for multiple models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Because of optimization and external API Requirments, I have to handle a big and nested query into many models. Is that possible using Ember-data? The project is quite large, and I don't want to use something different cause of clarity of the code.

I'm interested in something like this:

```
get(this, 'store').query('models', params) 
// API result: 
//{  
//  toys: [...somethinData], 
//  food: [...somethinData], 
//  cars: [...somethinData] 
//}
```

After the request, I'd like Ember to allocate data for each model. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to you `Ember.RSVP.hash` for that.

```
model(parameters) {
  var store = this.get('store');
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    student: store.findRecord('student', parameters.id),
    teacher: store.findAll('teacher'),
  });
},
```

and then use `{{model.teacher.name}}` in the template.

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/RSVP/methods/hash?anchor=hash

https://emberigniter.com/load-multiple-models-single-route/

Comment: There are multiple requests to API separately for each model :(